# Intuitive steps can be used during a proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Im trying to prove that: if $A \cup C = B \cup C$ and $A \cap C = B \cap C$ then $A = B$

I started assuming that $A \neq B$ then in a intuitive way i can see that $$((A \cup C = B \cup C) \land A \neq B) \Rightarrow A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq C$$
And from this in an intuitive way i concluded that:
$$((A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq C) \land A \neq B) \Rightarrow A \cap C \neq B \cap C$$

Which i think its a contradiction in relation to the original sentence, then $A = B$ is need to  be true to $A \cup C = B \cup C \land A \cap C = B \cap C$ be also, so i ended with:
$$(A \cup C = B \cup C \land A \cap C = B \cap C) \Rightarrow A = B$$

### I feel like i missed steps to make it correct, i want to know how can i fix this and if my atempt was totally wrong i want to know the directions to do it properly.

**Other implication from accepted answer**

$x \in B \Rightarrow x \in B \cup C$, and by premise $B \cup C = A \cup C$ then we have

$$x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A \cup C$$
$$x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A \lor x \in C$$
$$(x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A) \lor (x \in B \Rightarrow x \in C)$$
But $x \in B \land x \in C \Leftrightarrow x \in B \cap C$ and from this we have
$$(x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A) \lor (x \in B \land x \in C\Rightarrow x \in B \cap C)$$
And by our premise we have $B \cap C = A \cap C$, then we got
$$(x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A) \lor ((x \in B \land x \in C)\Rightarrow x \in A \cap C)$$
$$(x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A) \lor ((x \in B \land x \in C)\Rightarrow x \in A \land x \in C)$$
$$(x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A) \lor (x \in B \Rightarrow (x \in C \Rightarrow x \in A \land x \in C))$$
So in any case case we have $x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A$ then $B \subseteq A$

Comment: Intuition is not sufficient for a proof. It might provide a guide for how a proof may go, but what seems intuitive can often be wrong

Comment: The whole point of a proof is to avoid "intuition."  "Intuition" (whatever that might mean) can guide you on what avenues to explore, but it is strictly forbidden from any proof.  Some of the most important proofs violate "intuition," such as the proof that the total number of integers is the same as the total number of even integers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i will be trying to avoid intuition from now on, or when having some intuitive thiking, try to prove the thinking instead of assuming it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this proof would be to show, on the premise $A \cup C = B \cup C$ and $A \cap C = B \cap C$, that $x \in A \implies x \in B$ and $x \in B \implies x \in A$. These two implications give $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ respectively, and in turn $A = B$.

- First, we want to begin with the statement $x \in A$.
- Since $x \in A$, we know $x \in A \cup C$ as a result.
- However, by our premise, this means $x \in B \cup C$ as a well.
- Thus, at least one of $x \in B$ or $x \in C$ holds.

Obviously if $x \in B$ we're done. We continue instead on the premise $x \in C$ and see that in turn leads to $x \in B$.

- Then we must have $x \in C$ per the previous.
- Thus, $x \in A \cap C$ since it is in both.
- But $A \cap C = B \cap C$. Thus, $x \in B \cap C$.
- But this means that $x \in B$ and $x \in C$.
- Thus, $x \in B$.

Thus, $x \in A \implies x \in B$. This gives $A \subseteq B$.

I'll leave the reverse implication ($x \in B \implies x \in A$) to you.

Comment: Can you provide a feedback confirming if my edit is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, either $x \in C$ or $x \notin C$.
In the case $x \in C$, then $x\in A\cap C$ but $x \notin B\cap C$.
In the other case $x \notin C$, then $x\in A\cup C$ but $x\notin B\cup C$. Both cases contradict the assumptions, so there does not exist $x \in A$ with $x \notin B$, and we conclude $A \subseteq B$.

This goes through similarly if $x\in B$ but $x \notin A$, and we conclude $B\subseteq A$. Therefore $A = B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\exists x \in A \setminus B$ and let's denote $C=\{x\}$ for all such $x $. Then we will have
$$(x \in A \land x \notin B) \Leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \in C) \Leftrightarrow (x \in B \land x \in C) $$
But last is false by $x$ definition